# How to Close Keyboard if the ModalBottomSheetLayout closes in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Im working with Jetpack Compose and having a ModalBottomSheetLayout with a TextField. While Closing the bottom sheet, the keyboard it not going off.

Keyboard should hide, when ModalBottomSheetLayout dismisses.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {
    val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    BackHandler(state.isVisible) {
        scope.launch {state.hide()}
    }

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(sheetState = state, sheetContent = {
        TextField(value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Search") },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )

        LazyColumn {items(50) {...}}
    }) {
            Button(onClick = { scope.launch { state.show() } }) {
                Text("Click to show sheet")
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-programmatically) question, but this is not applicable for this scenario. As this is based on Composable.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/taehwandev/ComposeKeyboardState

Comment: I can't add an answer so I'll write my code to solve this issue here

`LaunchedEffect(Unit) {`
        `snapshotFlow { state .currentValue }`
            `.collect { if (it == ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) { focusManager.clearFocus()`
                   `keyboardController?.hide() } } }`

Comment: I solved the issue with this code... ```LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.currentValue) {
        // For hiding the keyboard & removing the Focus on hiding the sheet.
        if (state.currentValue == ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
            keyboardController?.hide()
            focusManager.clearFocus()
        }
    }```